# Customise toolbar above iPad keyboard adding a single line textfield aka SMS style

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, toolbar

Customise toolbar above iPad keyboard adding a single line textfield aka SMS style

I have ipad app with landscape  locked view with multiple textfields that I dont want to scroll up but like to enter single line text via a textfield in the toolbar, next to the Done, Next and Previous buttons. I am new to coding and built the app except for this customisation of the toolbar any help would be excellent :)